# Should You Apply for a Position if You Might Not Take It?

Tags: recruitment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should one go to interview for a job he doesn't intend to accept if offered?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/should-one-go-to-interview-for-a-job-he-doesnt-intend-to-accept-if-offered)

If there's a position that you're interested in, but you know there's a good chance their offer won't beat your current position, should you still apply? Is it considered rude to apply for a position, get through the whole interview process, then decide you'll keep your current position?

Comment: Hi Jeff Allen -- I've closed this as a duplicate of the linked question. If you think there are differences between the two such that your question would get different answers, please edit the question and it could be reopened. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no harm in applying for a position that you're not sure you'd take.

If you're currently employed, the interviewer will almost certainly ask about why you're thinking about leaving your current position.  If your concern is primarily about salary, as an example, they'll probably ask about your current salary and/or ask what sort of ballpark salary range you'd need an offer to come in at to leave your current position and/or tell you the salary range of the position and ask whether that is something you'd consider.  If your concern is about something other than salary, the conversation will be about whatever those concerns are (health plans, retirement plans, flex time, etc.)  If it becomes clear at that point that they wouldn't be able to make an offer that you would accept, you can thank them and politely remove yourself from consideration.

Answer (score 3):

You say there's a *good chance* it won't beat the current position, but that *isn't* a 100% guarantee which means you *might* get an offer that's better than your current position. So I say go for it! You might be surprised!