# What to do if I mistakenly accept two incompatible offers

Tags: recruitment

I got offers from two companies and mistakenly accepted both offers. Can I now choose whichever job of those two that I want?

Are there any legal issues regarding this situation?

Comment: Is there any non-compete clause in the contracts? what do you mean by accepting the two offers? are they full-time jobs? Could you manage your time to have two works at the same time? without more information, it's hard to give you a good answer

Comment: They are full-time jobs.I got offers from above two companies if i accept both offers and finally will chose one.Is it problem to me?Any legal issue?

Comment: If you accept both offers it will be an issue. You have made an agreement to be employed at both of their companies and is the same reason a company promising to hire you then retracting it at the last minute will get themselves in hot water.

Comment: `if i accept both offers and finally will chose one` then you just accept one offer.

Comment: Can you clarify this because you're asking "can I?" while at the same time saying you already have accepted two offers? Legal implications would require specifying a country but are likely out of scope here. Professional / reputational implications have been covered before on questions like [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4478) and [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11143).

Answer (score 5):

> Can I accept both offers?

Why would you? Assuming it's full time jobs, you can only work one. And since you have both offers, everything is on the table, you can decide freely. The decision is not getting easier by waiting, the offers won't magically change, especially not after accepting them.

With two offers on the table, there is really only so many ways to screw this up. One way is to take an offer and then not follow up on it. Obviously bonus points for screwing over both.

You will notice that "your word" actually is a commodity. It can be worth something, or it can be worth nothing. That is your decision. If you say what you mean and mean what you say, your word is worth something. Break promises and lie and it's not worth anything.

So bottom line, you have no benefit accepting both. You cannot work both jobs. So one of them will find out you deceived them which may or may not be legal trouble (consult a local lawyer for that) but certainly is a problem for your reputation. People talk about bad candidates. Don't be their topic of discussion, because you will want a next job after whichever you pick. Maybe even at the other company. And you might not get it, because you screwed them, or they talked to the next company that wants to hire you and they prefer the candidate not known for lying.

Bottom line is: deception is never a good thing, but people sometimes consider it when they think they can gain something. There is not even something to gain here. Don't lie.

Comment: By mistack i accept two offers now can i choose one what ever i want?

Comment: @user105818 You should have made it clear in the question, as it changes the scope. "Can I accept two full time offers" and "What to do if I mistakenly accept two incompatible offers" will lead to different answers

Answer (score 2):

> They are full-time jobs.I got offers from above two companies if i accept both offers and finally will chose one.

It sounds like you want more time to decide, so instead of asking for that you're planning on saying that you'll accept both offers, and then before signing any legal paperwork, rescinding on (let's say) company B's offer later.

I personally *really* wouldn't advise doing this - as well as being unethical, it'll likely result in you being blacklisted at company B in the future, and possibly get yourself a reputation from anywhere else that company B talks to. If recruiters are involved, the same applies to them.

If you want more time to decide, just say so.

> By mistack i accept two offers now can i choose one what ever i want?

...ok, so this puts a yet further different slant on the question, but the above still applies. If you've done this in error, then *immediately* send a follow up message to the company you don't want to work for rescinding your acceptance, and apologising profusely for your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take their interview first, if they accept it and want you to working in their company, you can said to them you need time to think and consider.

After that 2 interview, you can choose which company do you want to work.