# I have accepted the offer and then turn down can that company block me for other companies?

Tags: job-offer

I have accepted the offer and then turn down at last moment can that company block me for other companies ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Taking a job after already tentatively accepting another offer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11143/taking-a-job-after-already-tentatively-accepting-another-offer)

Answer (score 2):

No they cannot. They do not control "other companies"

What they can do is never enter a contract with you again. Tell their subsidiaries to never enter a contract with you again. And *maybe* they can talk to other companies in their network about what happened and those other companies can draw their own conclusions. However, that might be illegal where you live, we cannot tell. But "illegal" does not mean companies don't do it.

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on the location? For instance, in India, you need a relieving letter.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Very true, but this scenario does not include having a relieving letter from the company OP is refusing to join.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Right, and that may be a problem in places such as India. The relieving letter is proof they no longer work somewhere. If they have a signed contract, that is proof they are employed there. Lack of relieving letter means lack of proof employment has ended.

Comment: @SouravGhosh You are from India, so if there is something in the OPs post that makes you know this is not the case, it would be great if you could point it out.

Comment: The employment never started in the first place if I got that right. A relieving letter or even just references only make sense if actual time was spent on the job.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Right, that's why I was trying to clarify. Let's say, OP works for company A now, has accepted an offer from company B and, before joining B, they opted out and want to join company C. So, they'll need relieving letter from company A to be submitted to company C. Company B has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @nvoigt Right, that's the point.

Comment: @nvoigt I don't know enough about Indian law to know if/when employment begins and ends. What I do know is there have been situations where companies have withheld or been slow to produce a relieving letter. So, if the company is pissed off, there is that chance...

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Being employed in India, I believe nvoigt is right, relieving letter is needed only if you have joined and  worked as an employee, accepting  job offer would not be considered as _employment_.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Is there a seperate document that gets signed when they actually start working?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie yes sir, including the actual work agreement (and a bunch of NDA and non-competes). Only after that, they get the employee ID, employee number, official email ID and other logins.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Strange, where I am from, the offer is the work agreement.

Comment: In any case, now that we have solved the case for India, we can be certain that this answer is now valid for all countries.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie what if already holding relieving letter of company A and attempting to joining company C

Comment: The relieving letter of Company A is irrelevant. (I'm not sure why that was introduced by others.) If you have a signed contract with Company B and no reliving letter from Company B, then yes, they can cause problems if you are in India. Having said that, they probably won't cause problems unless you have really stuffed them about, and they are vindictive. @SouravGhosh has indicated that in India, there there is a seperate employment contract you have to sign when you arrive. Hopefully you did not do that (as you indicate in another comment you actually left on the day of joining).

Answer (score 0):

Which country? That makes a huge difference.

What does "at the last moment" mean? If you were supposed to start on Monday 9am and you call in Monday 8:55am that you won't start work, you are most likely in breach of contract. Depending on the country, they can cause you all kinds of problems, and again depending on the country, they *will* cause you all kinds of problems.

If "at the last moment" means "two seconds before you were supposed to sign the contract", there is nothing they can do. Depending on the country again.

Comment: India "At the last moment" means on the day of joining after reporting time and it was an permanent role not a kind of contractual role.