# Starting a job and not liking it

Tags: interviewing

Suppose a person starts a job but does not like the domain. Is it okay for him to apply and interview for other jobs that are closer to his interests?

Comment: In the same company or elsewhere?

Comment: Did you know about the domain before accepting the job?  If not, you probably should have asked or researched.  If you did, why take the job if you don't like the domain?

Comment: Are you saying you could do the same job in a different domain and that would make it all better?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doing an interview after having already signed a contract](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10940/doing-an-interview-after-having-already-signed-a-contract)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, although do **not** do it on your employers time. As long as it says in your employment contract "either party can terminate employment at any time, for any reason" you are free to do as you please. Free market, yo!

Comment: Additionally, I suspect their are few (Western, anyway) countries where any clause preventing the employee from doing so would be valid.

Comment: I live in the US, and it depends on the state. If you live in an at-will employment state (which is most), then you are ok. I have to emphasize to **please** read your employment contract.

Comment: So what's the opposite - it's possible to be forced to stay at a workplace in the US?

Comment: No, but you may have to pay fines or damages or something like that. Again, you have to read the contract and see what it says. It's never against the law or anything to leave a job, but there could be repercussions.

Comment: Do you have any examples? In the UK, at least, this would almost certainly get laughed at in court.

Comment: A signing bonus. May be pro-rated. So if you leave in the first year you may have to pay back part of the signing bonus.