# Applied to test myself now have multiple job offers

Tags: job-offer, human-resources, hiring, relocation, rejection

A few months ago I got fired from 2 jobs back to back after couple of weeks. It was quite brutal they said I am not up to standards. I think it was partly true. I was complacent at work. I made a lot of mistakes. Then I started applying everywhere including places where I had no interest in taking jobs. The companies are all internationally known and well respected, loved, non-money driven, with amazing tech. It's absolutely proud honour to be working for them. And work is really amazing it's an absolute honour to serve their customers.

Unfortunately my circumstances means I can't really relocate to those places. I knew that during interviews. I took each one so seriously because I want to practice my skills, I did technical/competencies. I really gave them all I got knowing I wouldn't be able to accept. Part of me wish I didn't get accepted. But, now they are coming my way and I have multiple offers. When they call you ask about OK so can you relocate etc. I am so like yes that's not a problem. I can relocate I can take care of everything. Because of my partner I can't for next 2 years.

**I am absolutely freaking out right now.** Because when my circumstances changes I want to apply to those places again. I have zero idea how to go about turning them down. What I did was wrong and telling them the things about my circumstances. I need some good excuse and not destroy my future chances.

Comment: Tell each one you accepted a different offer and thank them for their time. But don't do this in the future - you wasted a lot of money and time by trying to boost your ego.

Comment: Also, a duplicate of this: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21463/attending-interviews-to-stay-sharp-if-you-reject-an-offer-and-then-apply-aga

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attending interviews "to stay sharp", if you reject an offer, and then apply again later - wouldn't this harm your chances of being hired?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21463/attending-interviews-to-stay-sharp-if-you-reject-an-offer-and-then-apply-aga)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Practice... They are all companies that I really wanted to work for. I just wanted to know the process and go far as I can. So when I eventually in a position to apply I am ready. I would know what areas I lacked and what areas I need to concentrate on coming year or two.

Answer (score 4):

#### Don't do this anymore...

Now in this time period is not the time to do this. People need jobs during the COVID-2019 situation. Nothing is wrong with applying for multiple jobs and having multiple interviews but your intentions need to be pure.

If your intentions are to practice interviewing, then stop what you are doing. As @Catsunami pointed out, you're wasting company time and money all because you want to practice. Recruiters get paid to bring people into the company and if you're not going to take their offers seriously then you're endangering their employment. If you need help practicing for interviews, ask a friend/family member or look for a third party that can provide some type of career guidance, i.e. occupational therapy.

---

#### What should have you done, knowing that you were not able to relocate at the moment?

You should have explained that you and your partner are planning on moving in the next few years. This is the truth and perhaps that's all you should have said, not mentioning why you wanted to interview with them in the first place.

---

#### What should you do now?

I think in order to preserve your name from the company, you should tell them that you have been comparing opportunities and made a decision to not pursue the hiring process for that particular company.

When a few years pass, they may not remember you but I wouldn't guarantee that. I think it would be okay to apply again once you and your partner relocate.

**But whatever you do: Don't lie again; don't waste a company's time and money again.** I fully support your efforts to maintain fresh interviewing skills but not like what you're doing now during this time of uncertainty.

---

#### What should you do after this is all over?

You should look for a *local* job until you and your partner are able to move.

Comment: Regards to covid-19 that's something. I started process before lockdowns. You're right and I really regret when so many are unemployed cost-cutting. I'm so blessed to be in a position to get offers. Regards to company resources/time. I wouldn't have much regret (if no covid-19). I had bad experiences ranging from recruiters only wanting their commission to rude/dismissive interviewers who wasted hours and sometimes days of my time, to getting fired because I use windows on unfamiliar tech while rest of team was on Mac and took me days to get things working (they knew before they hired me).